# How to identify duplicate combinations of two values in random order

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, duplicate

I am trying to identify the second duplicate combinations of cells across two (or more) columns. Complicating matters, the order of combinations varies.

My data looks something like this:

```
aaa   111
222   aaa
111   aaa
111   bbb
bbb   111
```

I'm looking for a formula that, for this example, would tell me that rows 1, 2 and 4 are the first instances of the combined values, whereas rows 3 and 5 are the second instances.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a formula..."* - I'm no expert, but you may need something like VBA to achieve this; you might get a kindly soul answering [here on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba), or over at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not hard to do with functions/formulas
if you’re dealing with only two columns. 
You’ll need three “helper columns” in addition to a results column,
and you’ll need to identify a string that never appears in your data. 
Let’s use columns `E` through `H`, and the string `/`:

- `E1` — `=IF(A1<B1, A1, B1)`
- `F1` — `=IF(A1<B1, B1, A1)`
- `G1` — `=E1 & "/" & F1`
- `H1` — `=COUNTIF(G$1:G1, G1)`

`E1` is the lesser (minimum) of `A1` and `B1`,
and `F1` is the greater of `A1` and `B1`. 
In other words, `E1` and `F1` contain the values of `A1` and `B1`,
but sorted into ascending order. 
Then `G1` is `E1` concatenated with `F1`, delimited with `/`. 
This is a unique, order-independent combination of the values `A1` and `B1`. 
E.g., `G1` and `G3` both contain `111/aaa`,
because rows 1 and 3 have `111` and `aaa` in Columns `A` and `B` in some order. 
Then Column `H` counts how many times this combination has appeared so far.

[image: sheet]

Note that `H3` and `H5` each contains `2`,
because rows 3 and 5 are the ones that have a combination for the second time. 
When I repeated the row 1 data in row 6, I got `H6` = `3`,
because that was the third time the combination of `111` and `aaa` appeared.

As long as the data can be numeric or textual,
this gets very complicated very fast if you want to do more than two columns. 
There’s a way to make it easier if the data are all numbers, however. 
Or, if you’re willing to stipulate a maximum length for your data
(e.g., nothing longer than three characters), it may become manageable.